# How to copy, clone or duplicate without subitems

Tags: item-clones, copy

I would like to make a copy of just the `Home` item, to some other location under home.

But `Copy`, `Clone` or `Duplicate` does this including its child items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sitecore` provides you the option to clone an item with or without its subitems.

So for this, you have to select the item and go to the `Configure` ribbon menu.

And you will find the option like this.

[image]

Once you click, a popup will appear where you can provide the location to clone.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the Powershell command, where you will need to define `Path` and `Destination` like below:

```
Copy-Item -Path "master:\content\home" -Destination "master:\content\home\page1"
```

You can refer to [here](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items)

Or you can copy the `home` item to the destination and then you can `delete subitems`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are the options using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions. Option 1 & 2 are using Sitecore API so you can use it in your C# code as well

**Option 1**

```
$soureItem = Get-Item "/sitecore/content/SiteHome"
$desitinationItem = Get-Item "/sitecore/content/SiteHome/Page"

$soureItem.CopyTo($desitinationItem, $soureItem.Name, [Sitecore.Data.ID]::NewID, $false)
```

**Option 2**

```
$soureItem = Get-Item "/sitecore/content/SiteHome"
$desitinationItem = Get-Item "/sitecore/content/SiteHome/Page"
[Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager]::CopyItem($soureItem, $desitinationItem, $false, $soureItem.Name, [Sitecore.Data.ID]::NewID)
```

**Option 3**

```
Copy-Item -Path "/sitecore/content/SiteHome" -Destination "/sitecore/content/SiteHome/Page"
```